# world map like Google Analytics

Tags: dictionary, charts, youtube, google-analytics

I'm trying to do an analytics tool for my site similar to what google has on Google Analytics and  and the analytics on Youtube. It's basically just a static world map that shows a different color for each country, depending on the amount of visits that came from that country.

After many hours searching around I could find absolutely nothing. Has anyone found or did anything like this? Maybe there's an API I'm missing?

I'm using php and javascript by the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating analytics map similar to Google Analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264326/creating-analytics-map-similar-to-google-analytics)

Answer (score 4):

According to [12264326](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264326/creating-analytics-map-similar-to-google-analytics#comment16443734_12264326):

Have you tried the Google Chart Tools api (https://developers.google.com/chart/) ?

There is a geo chart which I think is exactly what you are talking about. https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at Piwik alraedy? http://piwik.org/ It's an OSS "clone" of Google Analytics. You might either use it or check their source code. They have a map view as well and afaik it's written in PHP.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is I'd like to allow all of my users to see a map of who visited their profile... so it needs to be some kind of api where I can enter a list of countries an values and turn it into a map chart if that makes sense

Comment: Piwik has a map that does that... don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have chosen [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/) in my project. I was even able to extend it with a few features like display values on the map (not just in tooltips) and to fix several issues.