# Creating analytics map similar to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I'm building an admin panel here at work and recording some ip data from users who are downloading our itunes mp3's. We have the ip and location of the user, but I'd like some way of displaying that visually. Is there any jquery plugin or addon that would allow me to display the stats I collected visually on a map similar to the way Google Analytics does it?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I've looked around Google, but searching the words google analytics and map and jquery plugin continued to give me results that are unrelated to what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the Google Chart Tools api (https://developers.google.com/chart/) ?

There is a geo chart which I think is exactly what you are talking about. 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find it too. Greetings

Answer (score 1):

[jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com) could also be suitable here.