# google analytics Map Overlay data

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Where do i get the data from Google Analytics for creating a Overlay Map of the visitors to my domain similar to the one in Google Analytics.

I've read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264326/creating-analytics-map-similar-to-google-analytics) but that talks about how to represent the data as a map. Which i've already [figured out](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) to retrieve the data on your server.   You would then feed the data you get to a Geomap using the [Google Visualization Library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap)

Comment: could you please direct me to exactly which api in the Core Reporting API would help me get this info?